# Invocation for construction parameter in spring framework dependency injection

Tags: spring

I have a project in which we have 2 projects as below :

1. scripts - pom.xml, application-context.xml, test.properties
2. selenium web driver - pom.xml

1 calls the web driver constructor and the object from the application-context.xml through dependency injection as below:

```
<import resource="application-context.xml"/>
    <bean id="webDriverFactory" class="...Selenium">

<constructor-arg name="proxyip" value="${proxyip} == null ? null: ${proxyip]}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyport" value="${proxyport} == null ? null: ${proxyport}"/>
```

and

```
@Autowired
  private WebDriver webDriver;
```

in 1

In 2 i have the following code:

```
if (!proxyip.isEmpty() && !proxyport.isEmpty()) {
      proxy = create_proxy();
    }
```

I have lot of additional properties files so don't want to define a default and a dummy value for the proxyip/proxyport for them. Is there a way to define default values in the application-context.xml. I tried following but it didn't work.

```
<constructor-arg name="proxyip" value="${proxyip} == null ? null: ${proxyip]}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyport" value="${proxyport} == null ? null: ${proxyport}"/>
```

test.properties:

```
proxyip=ip
proxyport=port no
```

, works with

```
<constructor-arg name="proxyIP" value="${proxyip}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyPort" value="${proxyport}"/>
```

but
test.properties:

```
#proxyip=ip
#proxyPort=port no doesn't work with
```

in application-context.xml

```
<constructor-arg name="proxyip" value="${proxyip} == null ? null: ${proxyip]}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyport" value="${proxyport} == null ? null: ${proxyport}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define default values right in the references to you configuration properties, like this:

```
<constructor-arg name="proxyIP" value="${proxyip:127.0.0.1}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyPort" value="${proxyport:1234}"/>
```

you could have the defaults be empty values and then your code could check for that:

```
<constructor-arg name="proxyIP" value="${proxyip:}"/>
<constructor-arg name="proxyPort" value="${proxyport:}"/>
```

I don't think you can have a `null` value as a default, so I hope that an empty value is good enough.  Should be given the code you show.  In fact, I would think that trying to call `isEmpty()` wouldn't work with `null` values.